# Why I can't directly use the column from another table behind not in function?

Tags: mysql, notin

I have two tables. One is customers and another one is orders. This is the raw data to create the two tables:

```
Create table If Not Exists Customers (Id int, Name varchar(255));
Create table If Not Exists Orders (Id int, CustomerId int);
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('1', 'Joe');
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('2', 'Henry');
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('3', 'Sam');
insert into Customers (Id, Name) values ('4', 'Max');
insert into Orders (Id, CustomerId) values ('1', '3');
insert into Orders (Id, CustomerId) values ('2', '1');
```

And now I have to write a SQL query to find all customers who never order anything.

This is the correct answer:

```
select
name as customer
from
customers
where
customers.id
not in
(select
customerid
from
orders);
```

This is my answer:

```
select
name as customer
from
customers
where
customers.id
not in
orders.customerid;
```

And the MySQL response to my codes is "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'orders.customerid' at line 8".

What's wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the reference to the orders table. This ref for a valid SQL syntax must be declared in  proper FROM  and WHERE clause or in a proper JOIN clause

For "not in" you could use left join and check for null

```
    select  name as customer
    from    customers
    left join orders on orders.customerid = customer.id
    where   orders.customerid is null
```

If you don't declare the reference to the table orders simply the db engine can't know from which table must be retrieved the column value. The table declaration must be explicit and assigned in the proper clause (from or join).

Answer (score 0):

`IN`, which is not a function BTW, needs a "set" or "list" as second operator which can typically be obtained by a subquery (or by giving a bunch of comma separated literals). In your case the subquery needs to get all customer IDs from the orders. So you might try:

```
SELECT c.name AS customer
       FROM customers c
       WHERE c.id NOT IN (SELECT o.customerid
                                 FROM orders o);
```

But instead of using `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery might be a better, possibly more performant solution here, especially if an index on `(orders.customerid)` exists:

```
SELECT c.name AS customer
       FROM customers c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM orders o
                                WHERE o.customerid = c.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask "why" about a language that's almost a half-century old. With respect, some of those language-design decisions are hard to recover. To get a perfect answer you need to track down Codd, Chamberlin, and Boyce. Why ask why?

At a more abstract level: SQL is fundamentally a set-manipulation language. Tables contain sets of rows. SELECT queries make their own sets -- they're even called result sets -- from other sets of rows.

In the SQL world, a column is not a set by itself. You can make a set from a column by saying things like this.

```
SELECT customerid FROM orders
```

And, the NOT IN() operation takes a set with just one column as its parameter.  So you can give NOT IN() and IN() sets but not columns.